# Change input and output shapes in onnx model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm quite new to machine learning, so I apologize in advance for the question.

I have a pre-trained onnx model, with defined input and output shapes.

Is it possible to change those values?

I looked at possible solutions, trying to use for example `onnxruntime.tools.make_dynamic_shape_fixed`, but since the model has an already fixed shape, this fails.

I'm also looking into converting the model to tensorflow format, and trying to modify the shapes from there, but I did not get very far on it.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow newcomer to machine learning, I'll do my best to help!

One approach is to convert it into dynamic model then try `onnxruntime.tools.make_dynamic_shape_fixed`

here is how you can make it dynamic :

```
ONNX_PATH = 'model.onnx'
model = onnx.load(ONNX_PATH)

model.graph.input[0].type.tensor_type.shape.dim[2].ClearField('dim_value')
model.graph.input[0].type.tensor_type.shape.dim[3].ClearField('dim_value')

ONNX_PATH = 'dynamic_model.onnx'
onnx.save(model, ONNX_PATH)
```

Replace `[2]` and `[3]` in the code with the indices of the dimensions you want to change. This code snippet demonstrates the process of making the model dynamic by removing the fixed input shape constraints, allowing for variable input shapes during inference.